# Условие, если результат интервала больше одного года

Tags: c#, дата

Есть две текстовых полей и проверка даты с условием если больше года.

Первая текущая дата и вторая дата окончания (сами заполняем поле).
Нужна проверка если больше 12 месяцев то ошибка

**Код:**

```
DateTime dateBegin = DateTime.Parse(txtDateBegin.Text);
DateTime dateEnd = DateTime.Parse(txtDateEnd.Text);
TimeSpan sp = dateEnd - dateBegin;
if (DateTime.IsLeapYear(dateEnd.Year))
{
    if (sp.Days > 366)
    {
        args.IsValid = false;
        CV_InsDates.ErrorMessage = "Ошибка";
    }
}
else
{
    if (sp.Days > 365)
    {
        args.IsValid = false;
        CV_InsDates.ErrorMessage = "Ошибка";
    }
}
```

Правильна ли будет данная проверка (проверка только на дату окончания)?
C каким числом сравнивать 366 или 365, как определить сколько дней в году?

Comment: Нет, можете проверить на 27.02.2016-27.02.2017 http://ideone.com/CaRtFr

Comment: Я так понимаю нужно чтобы разница между датами была не более одного года?

Comment: @Vadim Ovchinnikov, да, вопрос был на какую дату поставить IsLeaoYear() на дату окончания?

Comment: @Zhandos очень рекомендую изменить ваш вопрос, чтобы он был полезен для общества. 1. Зачем здесь `asp.net`? Вы можете переделать вопрос про даты (допустим на метод который возвращает `bool` и убрать специфику `asp.net`). 2. Указать про ваше желание чтобы код возвращал `bool`: является ли разница менее 1 года. Тогда ваш вопрос будет более общим и полезным.

Comment: Проверка _високосный год или нет (в заданном периоде)_, это как? Если менее одного года интервалы?

Comment: @Zhandos ещё просьба поменять код на метод, который возвращает `bool` и принимает начальную дату и конечную и убрать куски, специфичные для `asp.net`.

Comment: @Zhandos Вы изменили текст вопроса. Мне кажется, неудачно. Вы ставите задачу, в которой Вам нужна проверка.в МЕСЯЦАХ. Но ниже просите совета по проверке в ДНЯХ.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Не вполне понятно откуда такое странное условие. Но если уж оно есть - зачем вообще разделять года на високосные и нет, если можно просто сравнить две даты?

```
if (dateBegin < dateEnd.AddYears(-1)) {
  // Ошибка
}
```

Вот 4 варианта условий, которые можно использовать в зависимости от задачи (что считать годом):

- `dateBegin < dateEnd.AddYears(-1)` - разрешает (28 фев... 29 фев);
- `dateBegin.AddYears(1) < dateEnd` - запрещает (28 фев... 29 фев), но разрешает (28 фев ... 28 фев);
- `dateBegin <= dateEnd.AddYears(-1)` - запрещает (28 фев ... 28 фев), но разрешает (29 фев ... 28 фев);
- `dateBegin.AddYears(1) <= dateEnd` - запрещает (29 фев ... 28 фев).

Comment: сравнил две даты                                                       if (dateEnd.AddMonths(-12).AddDays(1) > dateBegin)

Comment: @Zhandos а чем `AddYears` плох? Зачем `.AddMonths(-12)`-то?

Comment: @Zhandos кстати, ваше условие эквивалентно моему третьему варианту

Answer (score 1):

Я бы сильно старался избегать разницы извлечения по годами из-за високосного года из-за "велосипедов" и соответствующих багов. К примеру, вы не учли случаи

1. Когда в первой дате високосный год и дата ранее 29 февраля.
2. Когда во второй дате високосный года и дата ранее 29 февраля.

Чтобы узнать разницу в годах нужен код (взят с [англ. SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4127396/1548895))

```
DateTime zeroTime = new DateTime(1, 1, 1);

TimeSpan span = startDate - endDate;
// Because we start at year 1 for the Gregorian
// calendar, we must subtract a year here.
int years = (zeroTime + span).Year - 1;
```

Затем проверяете

```
bool isValid = years < 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

> Как определить количество дней в периоде?

Есть метод [DateAndTime.DateDiff](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms127413(v=vs.110).aspx), который возвращает число интервалов времени между двумя Date значениями.

Comment: Хорошо бы немного расширить ответ, чтобы его не удалили как "ссылку на ответ вместо ответа"

Comment: Да ради бога. Только это будет медвежья услуга автору, если он не успеет увидеть ссылку, и никакой пользы остальным.

Comment: А в C# этот класс разве есть?

Comment: MSDN считает, что есть. Желаете с ней поспорить?

Comment: Нет, не желаю :) Забыл подключить Microsoft.VisualBasic. Интересно, почему не продублировали в стандартном DateTime этот метод

Comment: @Kromster, думаете msdn может исчезнуть? :)

Comment: @Visman ну на самом деле может - вернее, конкретную страницу могут снести в архив. Но найти её там по названию не составит труда. А вот копипастить статью оттуда сюда... длинная она. Да и смысл?

Comment: Ловите правку ;-) А еще можно добавить пример использования

Comment: Тогда бы в первую голову поправить сам вопрос. Ибо название не соответствует содержанию. А выбранный автором метод решения (что само по себе ошибка) если не ошибочен, то вряд ли оптимален.